# How to disable Content-Length check?

Tags: http, proxy, nginx, http-headers, http-content-length

Is there a way to disable checking for `Content-Length` header in the `PUT` requests on nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tri [ngx_headers_more module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule#more_clear_input_headers). This module can modify the output headers with the **more_set_header** and **more_clear_headers** directives.

Comment: a more specific answer?